# Only from PHP: Unable to connect APNS gateway.push.apple.com:2195

Tags: php, ios, ruby, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

*It's a late night. I just spent 10 hours in google/stackoverflow search and experiments. And seems I hate Apple Push Notifications. I'm totally frustrated and will appreciate any help.*

*Thank you.*

### The problem:

The PHP code for sending Apple Push Notifications, which successfully worked two weeks ago stopped to work now and throws following errors:

```
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in /home/...
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /home/...
```

It stopped to work on two separate servers, which are using separate scripts for APNs sending.

### Environment:

Servers: CentOS 6.5 with PHP 5.4.32 and Ubuntu 14.04.3 with PHP 5.5.9

APN: In production mode

Certificates: tested with 700+ push notifications.

One of the servers is using https://github.com/immobiliare/ApnsPHP, other - https://github.com/antongorodezkiy/wp-apn, on localhost I tested simple file without using any third party code.

### Investigation:

For all cases below I used the same active device token and the same production PEM certificate.

#### php

However, even this simple code **doesn't work** on both servers and localhost and return the same error as above:

```
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', '/absolute/path/to/apn_prod.pem');

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
```

I also tried to play with `stream_context_set_option()` options, include `entrust_2048_ca.cer`, etc, and even some options from [this article](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/improved-tls-defaults). Although provided code worked without any modifications before August 2015.

#### openssl

**Connection worked** with openssl ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2265/_index.html)):

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195 -cert /absolute/path/to/apn_prod.pem -debug -showcerts -CAfile /absolute/path/to/server-ca-cert.pem
```

And got with `CONNECTED(00000003)` and `Verify return code: 0 ( ok )`.

#### telnet

**Connection worked** with telnet:

```
-sh-4.1$ telnet gateway.push.apple.com 2195
Trying 17.172.233.150...
Connected to gateway.push.apple.com.
```

#### [pecl apn](http://libcapn.org/php-apn/)

**It didn't send push notification**. I just tried to use adaptation of [sample code](http://libcapn.org/php-apn/doc/html/examples.html), but got the error `Invalid token`. The token is active and same token I used everywhere and for Houston and Ruby too.

#### [houston](https://github.com/nomad/Houston)

**It worked** with Houston

```
apn push "0346a53f...231d9d6abe11" -c /absolute/path/to/apn_prod.pem -m "Hello from the command line!" -e "production"
```

#### ruby

I'm not a Ruby programmer (yet at least), but after success with Houston, I found and adapted Ruby code without Houston dependency.

And **it worked**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'openssl'
require 'socket'
require 'json'

token = "0346a53f...231d9d6abe11"
cert = File.read("/absolute/path/to/apn_prod.pem")
ctx = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
ctx.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(cert, '') #set passphrase here, if any
ctx.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(cert)

sock = TCPSocket.new('gateway.push.apple.com', 2195) #development gateway
ssl = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(sock, ctx)
ssl.connect

payload = {"aps" => {"alert" => "Oh hai!", "badge" => 1, "sound" => 'default'}}
json = payload.to_json()
token =  [token.delete(' ')].pack('H*') #something like 2c0cad 01d1465 346786a9 3a07613f2 b03f0b94b6 8dde3993 d9017224 ad068d36
apnsMessage = "\0\0 #{token}\0#{json.length.chr}#{json}"
ssl.write(apnsMessage)

ssl.close
sock.close

puts "End"
```

## Questions:

1. What's wrong with PHP? Is there some bug related to this issue? (I didn't find bug report though)
2. Any ideas how to solve this issue?
3. Any ideas what could be the difference in PHP and Ruby cases (I assume that Python or Perl could work fine too)? I even tried to read PHP sources, but without success to understand how `stream_socket_client()` implemented.

#### *Please help.*

Comment: Did you get APNS notifications working? I have the same issue on PHP dev server with production server running as expected with shared codebase.

Comment: @ViktorSulak yes, I've fixed it. Please check my answer ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/33015070/741782 ) and thank you for reminding me about this ticket

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the issue and fixed it.

The **problem** was in .pem certificate. Somehow there were two certificates in one file for both production and development .pem files. The same .pem file with two certificates was in the repo for a long time but APNs stopped to work only few months ago. Maybe something was upgraded/changed on the Apple's side.

I assume the Ruby code somehow removes certificate duplication or maybe it took only first certificate, so it worked in Ruby.

However, the **solution** was to remove the second certificate from the .pem file. After that APNs started to work and they work now (I received some just yesterday).

Answer (score 0):

If you're just reusing an old Certificate Signing Request (CSR), make sure to remove the expired/old APNs certificate from your Keychain before exporting the new one and its private key as p12 file. If you don't do that, the PEM file you generated out from the exported p12 will still contain the expired/old certificate which doesn't goes well with Apple's Push provider. Thus resulting to `unable to connect to ssl...`.